# Sencha Touch : net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

Tags: encoding, http-headers, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, gzip

I'm using a web service to receive json encoded data. It was working fine. Recently I have enabled `gzip` compression in my web server. After that I'm getting this error in my sencha touch application.But it's working fine when I checked the url  via web browser. Any idea?

```
net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is thrown by the browser; not Sencha.

- The request should contain the correct header: `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate`
- The response should contain the header telling the client which compression scheme is being used: `Content-Encoding: gzip`

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression.

Also check that the content is actually compressed using the specified scheme, see the following thread: [Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039804/error-330-neterr-content-decoding-failed)