# why there is error while compressing .js files

Tags: asp.net, iis, c#-4.0, iis-7

why net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED error message is coming for .js file?? I was surfing my website, and i got this error for three .js files. I checked this is due to compression failed. But I don't understand why compression is getting failed. status code for all .js file is 200.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039804/error-330-neterr-content-decoding-failed

Comment: @Venkata Panga ,Reason I got, but what is solution??

Answer (score 0):

If you use IIS-7+ then Check this IIS httpCompression http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httpcompression

And for other reference:

- [Troubleshooting-iis-compression-issues](http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/performance-issues/troubleshooting-iis-compression-issues-in-iis6-iis7x)
- [Use .Net 2.0 compression library and HttpModule to compress your webpages.](http://www.jigar.net/articles/viewhtmlcontent266.aspx)
- http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2007/Jun/22/IIS-7-and-JavaScript-Compression-not-working-consistently

Comment: @ Venkata Panga, staticCompressionIgnoreHitFrequency, enter True to disable the behavior that a static file is compressed only if it is hit a certain number of times within a time period. can you tell me, number of hit required and time period in which hits to be done?

Comment: In request header Accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, is missing, but in response header Content-encoding: gzip is present. does it cause compression failed. if yes, how to avoid it??

Comment: In IIS7, if you `Enable staic/dynamic content compression` and set this property `staticCompressionIgnoreHitFrequency` to `False`then no need to worry about other settings. Regarding number of hits thats separate chapter and if you use IIS 6 then you may think about it, [read this article](http://www.ksingla.net/2006/06/changes_to_compression_in_iis7/). Coming to Request Header `Accept-Encoding: gzip` browser should sends this header.