# net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED for PHP encoded variable

Tags: php, jquery, zlib

I have tried using the solutions like adding **header("Content-Encoding: none");** and changing ini values **ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off'); but still failed.
       ini_set('output_buffering', 'Off');
       ini_set('output_handler', '');**
I am getting this error for a function which uses an encoded variable in a file.
I have the below code in my PHP file and using the variables in the included javascript file as parameter to call a function.(The script tags are in a .php file,not sure if that may be an issue?)

```
   <script>
     folderNameInJS = <?php echo json_encode($_POST['folderNameByUser']);?>;
     parentFolder   = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['parentDir']);?>;
  </script>
```

The function is this one in my js file:

```
function getFolder(folderNameByUser){
$.post(USER_DASHBOARD+'file_share/navigateFolder.php', {'folderNameByUser':folderNameByUser},     function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
 // alert(data);
 $('#mainDashboard').html('<div class="rightContainer"><div class="tabLoader"></div></div><div  class="clear"></div>');
 $('#mainDashboard').html(data);
  })
```

}

I call it at different places in the script.
**This works as expected on the local machine but fails on server**. How can I debug this and resolve

Comment: pls read: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039804/error-330-neterr-content-decoding-failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039804/error-330-neterr-content-decoding-failed)

Comment: quick hint, pasting error into google search will find results more often than not