# Error Content Decoding in GZip filter

Tags: php, smarty, gzip

When I use `$smarty->loadFilter('output','gzip');` in my program, the Chrome cannot load my website on localhost and show this error:

```
This webpage is not available

ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED
```

When I remove `loadFilter` everything seems ok !

What is the problem ?

Comment: Did you try to use fiddler to view the result you get from your server? Did you try in firefox/ie - do you get the same results? This might be a security thing in Chrome. Need more information to help.

Comment: @Dekel I don't have this problem on server, just in local, in FireFox and Safari have the same result, this problem occured in last 2 days, before that I Don't have problem

Comment: @Dekel PHP 5.5.23 on Mac

Comment: ok, and what about fiddler? what exactly is the output there?

Comment: @Dekel I cannot understand your mean of 'fiddler' :(

Comment: So I guess google is your best friend :) http://bit.ly/1Molcq2

Comment: btw, did you check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039804/error-330-neterr-content-decoding-failed ? Same error that you got and several solutions there...