# Where is the content-encoding set for WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, compression, gzip

I disabled a WordPress caching/compression plugin, and my site is still stuck in returning headers that say the content-encoding is gzip. It should be text/html.

When I load any page, even wp-admin, Chrome says `ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED`.

The first answer displays the problem: [Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039804/error-330-neterr-content-decoding-failed)

Here are the headers:

[image]

.htaccess of `/m/`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /m/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /m/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /m/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /m/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

.htaccess of `/`:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

Options +FollowSymLinks


RewriteEngine On
```

I'm just not sure how to get rid of the gzip. Any ideas?

Comment: usually look in header.php and called files, some caching plugins will write into <head> but are you loading pages from the server or browser cache?

Comment: @David I'll have to check that too

Comment: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 vs Content-Encoding: gzip. Getting rid of gzip is the wrong approach. gzip is a good thing. Typically for WP caching plugin problems you want to check your htaccess file for leftover caching code and also your wp-config.php file for the WP cache constant:  WP_CACHE leftover caching plugin code and/or other similar code in the wp-config.php file.

Comment: I already tried removing everything from wp-config and I'll add the htaccess to the original post.