# how to fix -ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED in Wamp

Tags: php, apache, drupal, wamp

I have Drupal7 site. It was running fine with no issues. But suddenly I am getting

> This site can’t be reached
>     The webpage at http://localhost:8080/mysite/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
>   ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

Its not the issue in any specific browser, but same error with any browser.

Checked links:-

1. [Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039804/error-330-neterr-content-decoding-failed)
2. http://stefantsov.com/fixing-err_content_decoding_failed-in-apachephp/
3. https://www.howtoforge.com/firefox-content-encoding-error-google-chrome-error-330-net-err_content_decoding_failed-unknown-error

I tried reinstall, reimport database etc things but same error persists.

Its been now about 24hours getting this error.

**What should I do now to get rid of this error & re-run my site smoothly.**

Other Info

- Drupal 7
- wamp 2.5
- php5.5.12

Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: So what did you change **just before it stopped working**

Comment: Did you install this site from scratch, or did you download a live site to develop in using WAMPServer

Comment: @RiggsFolly. Updated password of the user using sql query

Comment: @RiggsFolly. Added the following line in my module.`header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: @RiggsFolly.. downloaded a live site

Comment: _downloaded a live site_ Well in that case you need to check your WAMPServer PHP/Apache config matches your LIVE server config

Comment: @RiggsFolly..I downloaded some weeks back after the required configuration it was running fine but after these the updates mentioned I am getting the this error. Hence I just reinstalled the site plus reimported the database from mysite.sql

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issues in xampp server on localhost.

I spend almost 2-3 hours to figure it out so i am sharing the solution to save someone else time. Below is the solution that work for me.

**1)**  Edit the php.ini files of xampp/wampp

**2)**  Enable the extension  `zlib.output_compression = On` If it will be Off

**3)**  Un-comment the code from `;zlib.output_compression = On`  to `zlib.output_compression = On` in commented using `";"`

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved my problem.

Comment: @HassanAl-Jeshi  my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Error 330 seems to be linked to when a site's HTTP response headers claim that the content is gzip encoded, but it isn’t. Are you using gzip compression? 
Try turning it on, or off via the htaccess file, or check here for other alternative ways to enable it. https://varvy.com/pagespeed/enable-compression.html