# ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

Tags: php, apache, apache2

I try to run project based on php on my local apache2 server but after starting server a receive an error:

> The webpage at http://localhost:8080/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
>   ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

on both browsers - chrome and firefox. I tried some tips how to overcome it (zlib.output_compression = On in php.ini, in htacces etc.) and other 'tricks' but nothing works - still the same error...

> Request headers: 
>   Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br

and

> Response headers: content-encoding:gzip

so it should be ok, I think. In apache error.log there are no errors.
Im using Ubuntu 16.04 and php7.1

I will appreciate any help how to overcome this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error 330 (net::ERR\_CONTENT\_DECODING\_FAILED):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039804/error-330-neterr-content-decoding-failed)

Comment: Duplicate has several approaches/possible reasons, please check those.