# What does ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

Tags: syntax-error

This is the error code I am getting. I am a novice at this and could really use some help. I happened to open the "developer" tool in Chrome and might have made a mistake or something because now I cannot see my slider or testimonials. Can anyone help? Sorry if my question is not posed correctly, I am having a panic attack and this is my first time using this form. The slider works fine in other browsers, just not Chrome -- all of a sudden.

```
GET https://fitkidsstage.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/css/settings.css?ver=5.1.6 net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED
jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
(index):1078 GET https://fitkidsstage.com/wp-content/themes/kindergarten/js/main.js?ver=4.9.5 net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED
(index):1080 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

Answer (score 2):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039804/error-330-neterr-content-decoding-failed):

> It happens when your HTTP request's headers claim that the content is gzip encoded, but it isn't. Turn off gzip encoding setting or make sure the content is in fact encoded.

This loads fine in Chrome (Version 65.0.3325.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)) though (exception running the script due to other missing dependencies), so your problem may be elsewhere.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=" https://fitkidsstage.com/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/css/settings.css?ver=5.1.6">
<script src="https://fitkidsstage.com/wp-content/themes/kindergarten/js/main.js?ver=4.9.5 "></script>


<body>

    <div>
        Hi
    </div>
</body>
```