# PHP | Getting ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED in Ajax request

Tags: php, opencart

I'm getting that silly error when calling an ajax request, and when I open the URL of the Ajax in the browser, I get the same error.

[image]

[image]

I've been in this for 2 months.
I removed my **.htaccess** and nothing changed.
This is happening only on local environment, not on production.

I tried adding

```
zlib.output_compression = On;
```

to my **php.ini** but did not change anything.

I'm using Opencart 2.2.0.0 | PHP 5.6 | Ubuntu LAMP

**UPDATE 1**

This is the code called via ajax:-

[image]

if I add a **print_r($data);** it prints the data array, but the issue occurs when it tries to return the rendered content of the view file, I tried to create another view file but got the same response.

**UPDATE 2**

Here is the request from devTools > network tab:-

[image]

and the response tab is empty, no response it returned.

**UPDATE 3**

[image]

Comment: Have you tried all the suggestions here ~ [Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED):](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039804/error-330-neterr-content-decoding-failed)? Remember, if you make changes to `php.ini`, you need to restart the HTTP server

Comment: put error_reporting in starting of your page
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37036144/5700401

Comment: Tried them all now, but did not work :(

Comment: Here I give you a [Present](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/AjaxWrapper/AjaxWrapper.php)  This is a AjaxWrapper class in PHP that will trap any output that happens inside of it, and most errors.  So that your JSON is still valid even if you have PHP errors.  `I've been in this for 2 months`  Hope you haven't been stuck on this for that long.  Also remove these `?>` from pure PHP files.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix 
thanks for help.
I don't think it is related to Ajax as I get the same response when accessing the URL from the browser normally and getting the response in the screenshot above, what do you think ?

Comment: `accessing the URL from the browser normally` an AJAX request is a HTTP request, a browser is a HTTP request.  The server dosn't know the difference.

Comment: can you please check the (UPDATE 1 ) above if it might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience this error comes up when there is a php error and compression is turned on.  Go to **Admin > System > Settings** and then to the **Server** tab and set **Output Compression Level** to **0**.  Also make sure **Display Errors** is set to **ON**.

Now inspect the response from your Ajax call and instead of a decoding error you will be able to see the actual error that's being reported.

Also remember if it's a FATAL error the script can crash before it even gets a chance to initialize the custom error handler and the the only way to get data about these will be in the webserver error logs.

Comment: Thanks so much!!
I tried disabling output compression from php.ini, but it seems like it wasn't taking effect, you saved me much much time.

Thanks alot again.

Answer (score 1):

The "<" often indicates that you are trying to json-decode html. Have you checked devtools and seen what is actually returned by the server?

I've seen this myself when requests for json-data has either returned html-formatted error messages or when the requesting user has not been logged in and the Ajax call has (erroneously) redirected to a login screen.

Comment: The "<" was returned because the page was trying to load a not existing CSS file, and the website returns the homepage instead of returning a 404 page, now I removed that call to the non-existing file and the issue still exists (but the "<" error in the devTools is gone).

Comment: Sounds like you are still not getting valid json-data, but based on the scarce info I have it's almost impossible to say why. Check for php-notifications, warnings etc which surely is muted in the production environment but may be present in your development setup. You should see this quite easily in devtools.

Comment: No json data used in the page, can you please check the (UPDATE 1 ) above if it might help.

Comment: @HazemTaha: Can you show the Response from the call from Chrome DevTools? (If you are not familiar with this: open DevTools, select Network tab, find and select the correct http-request and copy the text from the Respone-tab).

Comment: @HazemTaha: the last update shows the request, not the response (which is shown in the Resonse-tab).

Comment: The response is empty, please find the UPDATE 3 screenshot.

Comment: If the response is consistently empty I'm fresh out of suggestions to what may cause the problem. My approach would be to set a breakpoint on line 38 and single step through the code to see what is happening.